# Keep getting this TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EtsyProductSync')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have absolutely no clue what is causing this error and I am at my witts end.

Does anyone have any clue what in the world could possibly be causing this?

[image: Here is the the error]

````
export interface EtsyProductSync extends mongoose.Document {
  etsy_shop_id: string
  spicerack_shop_id: string
  synced_products: string[]
  created_at: Date
}

/* EtsyProductSyncSchema will correspond to a collection in your MongoDB database. */
const EtsyProductSyncSchema = new mongoose.Schema<EtsyProductSync>({
  etsy_shop_id: {
      type: String,
  },
  spicerack_shop_id: {
      type: String,
  },
  synced_products: {
      type: [String],
  },
  created_at: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
  },
})

export default mongoose.models.EtsyProductSync || mongoose.model<EtsyProductSync>('EtsyProductSync', EtsyProductSyncSchema```
````

Comment: Why are you exporting one or the other? Are you checking for existence of one of the models?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
export default mongoose.models?.EtsyProductSync || mongoose.model<EtsyProductSync>('EtsyProductSync', EtsyProductSyncSchema);
```